# cakephp retrieve data into controller from another table

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, mysql-error-1054

I'm using cakephp and I want that in my userController.php retrieve data from another table (ingredient_aliases).
This is the model of ingredientAlias

```
class IngredientAlias extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'IngredientAlias';
    public $useTable = 'ingredient_aliases';
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Ingredient' => array(
            'className'    => 'Ingredient',
            'foreignKey'   => 'ingredient_id'
        )
    );
...
```

I want to retrieve data form the table ingredient_aliases (last 10 created) from my userController.php

I have tried in this mode:

```
$this->loadModel('IngredientAlias', 2);
$ingg = $this->IngredientAlias->read();
$options['joins'] = array(
    array('table' => 'ingredient_aliases',
        'alias' => 'ing',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'foreignKey' => 'ing.user_id',
        'order' => 'ing.created DESC',
        'limit' => 3,
        'conditions' => array(
            'ing.user_id = User.id'
        )
    )
);
$options['conditions'] = array( );
$this->set('ingredient',$this->IngredientAlias->find('all', $options));
```

But this give me this error:
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'User.id' in 'on clause'

Can someone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply instantiate another model (table) on any controller or component by using the following.

```
$data = ClassRegistry::init('IngredientAlias')->find('first', array());
```

That's it. You will be able to access any data on any table.

Comment: Can I retrieve a specific field instead of all the column?